# How can I see the historical development of votes given to different answers?

Tags: support, feature-request

Based on the votes given for the different answers of [Python Multiprocessing with Distributed Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876898/python-multiprocessing-with-distributed-cluster) I want to decide which technology for distributed computing I should choose for myself.

As depicted in the sketch, the green answer / technology is possibly better for me as it gets more votes per period of time than the red answer.

How can I get a graph like the one depicted to decide on this criteria which technology / framework I should choose? (if the stackoverflow platform does not offer it - is there perhaps an e.g. github project that has this functionality?)

[image: sketch for development of votes over time]

Comment: In what way would a popularity contest help you decide what would be best for your unique scenario?

Comment: Try https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/83159/votes-over-time-for-a-specific-question-and-its-answers (mentioned in cross-site dupe https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152455) I haven't tried it out myself.

Comment: @cigien Thanks, that helped a lot :-)

Comment: They are quality votes, not popularity votes :/ You are going to make a decision based on how good questions/answers are. Really? I have to stress that Java is pretty popular and the tag sees a pretty continuous stream of very low quality material...

Answer (score 9):

Oh, ***no***.

This is why we don't allow these kinds of questions here - because of this very situation where you now wish to pick between technologies based on how popular we rate them.

Going to make this blanket and general recommendation.  If you're looking to research technologies and looking to make a decision that will drive what you build and how you build, **please do your own internal testing and decision making**.  Your use case may look completely different to the recommendations of utter strangers on the Internet who are disinterested in the success of your development efforts.